# Pear leaves going dark brown without usual signs of blister or fire blight

Tags: fruit-trees, pear, browning

We have about seven pear trees of various varieties, both Asian and European. Our Flemish Beauty is getting these dark brown leaves.

[image: dark brown patches on pear leaves]

There are just a few -- about thirty or so -- and none of the other trees are affected, nor are the fruits on this tree affected. There are no obvious signs of either blister or fire blight -- no sunken patches on the bark, no weeping patches or shriveled shoots (you can see in one picture that the spur is healthy).

[image: pear tree branch, showing dark brown leaves and unaffected spur]

Could this be a disease or merely underwatering? The tree doesn't look like it's getting much less water than the others.

Comment: Where in the world are you? My first guess woukd be frost

Comment: Profile info indicates Penticton, BC - 48°F/9°C is as low as it's been recently (July 26th) according to what I could find quickly.

Comment: yeah, close to Pentiction, so definitely not frost, although I do agree it looks like that. Historically, the last frost date is sometime in May, and the first one is sometime in October or (rarely) September.